# Complex operations between rows and columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to construct a function that calculates the Heiken Ashi candles to visualize the market prices differently. For this purpose I'm using python's pandas library. There exist some operations between columns and rows of different possitions that have to be done (eg. add value with previous cell and update the actual value), so I've managed to made those with a loop, but I think it must be a **most pandorable way** to do it. Can anyone tell me if it is really possible to eliminate the loop from my code?

```
def heikenashi(df):

    df['HA_Close'] = df[['Open','High','Close','Low']].mean(axis=1)
    ha_o = (df['Open'] + df['Close']) / 2  #Creating a Variable
    df['HA_Open'] = 0.0
    df['HA_High'] = 0.0
    df['HA_Low'] = 0.0

    df.ix[1, 'HA_Open'] = (df['Open'][0] + df['Close'][0]) / 2

    i = 2
    while i < len(df.index):
        df.ix[i, 'HA_Open'] = (df.ix[i-1, 'HA_Open'] + df.ix[i-1, 'Close']) / 2
        df.ix[i, 'HA_High'] = df.ix[i-1, ['High', 'HA_Open', 'HA_Close']].max()
        df.ix[i, 'HA_Low'] = df.ix[i-1, ['Low', 'HA_Open', 'HA_Close']].min()
        i += 1

    return df
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: couldn't you shift like this: `df['HA_Open'] = (df['HA_Open'].shift() - df['HA_Close'].shift())/2`

Comment: You can use the `applymap` function for that.
Please see the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Comment: @WoodyPride is not a sigle shift, I think is more something to do with a rolling(), since the values depend on a row that is being calculated previously.